# App Insights set up Visual Studio SDK not showing requests on portal

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I have an ASP.NET Web API project targeting .NET 4.8.

On top, it has an added an ASP.NET Core Configure Services `Startup.cs`.

It has a `Startup.cs`, Configure Services, .NET 4.8 and `app.config`.
I created an app insights resource on portal.Installed `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` nuget package, added the portal AI resource instrumentation key to `app.config`.

Then I used postman to send a request to the API with the expectation that I could see the request and profiler on App insights. No luck!

```
 Startup.cs
/*
 * API
 *
 * No description provided (generated by Openapi Generator https://github.com/openapitools/openapi-generator)
 *
 * The version of the OpenAPI document: 1.0.0
 * 
 * Generated by: https://openapi-generator.tech
 */

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Startup
    /// </summary>
    public class Startup
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration"></param>
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        /// <summary>
            /// The application configuration.
        /// </summary>
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services"></param>
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.

            services.AddCors(options => 
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                            .WithExposedHeaders("Wtoken")
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InstrumentationKey"];
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
            
            
            var secretKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenSecret"];
            
            //var issuer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Issuer"];
            //var audience = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"];

            services
                .AddAuthentication(opt =>
                {
                    opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    opt.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(x =>
                {
                    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    x.SaveToken = true;
                    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidIssuer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"],

                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey)),
                    };
                });


           


            services
                .AddMvc(opts => {
                    
                    opts.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new InputFormatterStream());
                    })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
                {
                    opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                    opts.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter
                    {
                        CamelCaseText = true
                    });
                });

            services
                .AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("1.0.0", new Info
                    {
                        Version = "1.0.0",
                        Title = "API",
                        Description = "API (ASP.NET Core 2.1)",
                       TermsOfService = ""
                    });
                    c.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FriendlyId(true));
                    c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
                    c.IncludeXmlComments($"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}{Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml");

                   
                    c.OperationFilter<GeneratePathParamsValidationFilter>();
                });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        /// <param name="env"></param>
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app
                .UseCors()
                .UseMvc()
                .UseDefaultFiles()
                .UseStaticFiles()
                .UseSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/openapi.json";
                })
                .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    //TODO: Either use the SwaggerGen generated Swagger contract (generated from C# classes)
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/1.0.0/openapi.json", "API");

                    //TODO: Or alternatively use the original Swagger contract that's included in the static files
                    // c.SwaggerEndpoint("/openapi-original.json", "API Original");
                });
            app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
   </configSections>
  <appSettings>

    
    <add key="EFConnstringKey" value=""/>  
    <!-- settings below here are global -->
      <add key="InstrumentationKey" value="27bafd84450"/>
    <add key="SmtpServer" value=""/>

    <add key="TokenSecret" value=" "/>
    <add key="Issuer" value=" "/>

    <add key="Audience" value=" "/>

    <add key=" " value=" "/> 
    <add key=" " value=" "/> 
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- leaving as sample, not used in code. 'connectionString' value is stored in connstring manager after replacing "&quot;" with "'" -->
   </connectionStrings>
  
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @Harshitha: can you suggest please?

Comment: Please share your Configuration Files?

Comment: What does `Configuration` in the 2nd line of code in startup class mean.It would be great if you share your folder structure and complete code of Startup file.

Comment: @Harshitha: Thank you. Updated with Startup.cs, config, properties.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide GitHub repo, if possible.So that I can try to run your app itself and can know the exact issue.

Comment: I have to setup the configuration from my end.Will work on it and let u know.

Comment: Are you able to see the traces in local?

Comment: @Harshitha: local meaning on visual studio?

Comment: I am looking for the profiler,bapi request that postman is sending to localhost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254982/discussion-between-harshitha-and-user575219).

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of points:

1. In the line below:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
```

Is there a reason for passing in the `Configuration` object? Normally, I would pass in an object of type `ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions()` if needed. Otherwise, I would use no parameter.

2. Have you tried adding this line:

```
builder.Services.AddServiceProfiler()
```

You may also need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Profiler.AspNetCore` Nuget package.